How to refrain SwiftUI unnecessary refreshing when using ObservableObject
import SwiftUI
class ViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var test = false
    var timer:Timer!
    init(){
    }
    func loadTimer(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.test = false
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .onAppear{
            viewModel.loadTimer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


In this code, I just keep setting test to false, and It keeps rerendering itself even if nothing changes.
Will it cause performance problems? If so, how to stop the swiftui view from rerendering?
I found the @Observerable may help, but it is only available in iOS 17.

ObservableObject's performance is so bad Apple is replacing it with Observable. Apple talks about it in one of the related WWDC videos from last year. ObservableObject does a complete invalidation because it only has 1 way of knowing when to invalidate/redraw objectWillChange. Value types are the most efficient because they use Hashable, Equatable and Identifiable to trigger redraws.

You can use TimelineView
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview

Overview A timeline view acts as a container with no appearance of its
own. Instead, it redraws the content it contains at scheduled points
in time. For example, you can update the face of an analog timer once
per second: TimelineView(.periodic(from: startDate, by: 1)) { context in AnalogTimerView(date: context.date) }

